# SSL Socket Connection to nginx not working on some android and ios devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ssl, nginx

I've developed a game in **react native** for both **android** and **ios**. It connects via sockets to **nginx server** which is running with a digi cert SSL certificate. Behind nginx, 4 **node.js** servers are running on 
 3000, 3001, 3002, 3017 ports respectively. The entire architecture sits inside a AWS EC2 c5.x instance. All inbound and outbound ports of AWS firewall are open for the testing purposes.

I can listen to the respective ports from my laptop browser and it is giving correct responses. Mobile App on the other hand communicate only via sockets.

Some of the devices can't connect to the server (socket 'connect' event is not listened and websocket connection err is displayed), while others can effortlessly connect.

**Following error is displayed:**

```
Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.onError (/home/ubuntu/TTP-Server/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:64:13)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (/home/ubuntu/TTP-Server/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/websocket.js:150:10)
    at WebSocket.onError (/home/ubuntu/TTP-Server/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/EventTarget.js:109:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at WebSocket.finalize (/home/ubuntu/TTP-Server/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:182:41)
    at ClientRequest._req.on (/home/ubuntu/TTP-Server/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:647:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
```

All the devices are above android 6 and ios 10 version

I have checked my website against an online SSL validator. It shows the following results:

[image]

Here are my related files and codes:

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events
{
  worker_connections 768;
}

http
{
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate    PATH_TO_CRT_FILE;
  ssl_certificate_key    PATH_TO_KEY_FILE;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  upstream lobby
  {
     server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  }

  upstream table_1
  {
     server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  }

   upstream table_2
  {
     server 127.0.0.1:3002;
  }

  upstream analytics
  {
     server 127.0.0.1:3017;
  }

  server
  {
    listen 443;
    server_name tpa;

    location /3000/
    {
      proxy_pass http://lobby/;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /3001/
    {
      proxy_pass http://table_1/;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /3002/
    {
      proxy_pass http://table_2/;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /3017/
    {
      proxy_pass http://analytics/;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
}
```

Inside my react native code, I have used node's [Socket.IO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) and i'm making connection using following code:

```
let options = {
   transports: ["websocket"],
   query: `userID=${this.props.phoneNumber}&ipAddress=${ip}&sessionId=${uuid}`,
   reconnection: true,
   reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
   path: "/3000/socket.io"
};

socket = io(`${Constants.serverIP}`, options);
```

It has given me sleepless night since the last 2 days. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: "Some of the devices can't connect to the server,.." is not a useful problem description. What is the nature of this failure to connect? Are there exceptions thrown, errors returned, timeouts, .... what?

Comment: Suggest using tcpdump and/or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on the servers to get more information on the problem.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Socket 'connect' event is not listened for the connection. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue after doing a lot of work. It might help someone else working on the same architecture.

After looking deep into the following multiple times:

- AWS architecture
- Nginx configuration
- nginx access and error logs
- network firewall
- node.js server logs

I came to the conclusion that it’s not a problem on Nginx or AWS side, there seemed to be problem from the domain or intermediate server problem.

I tried checking one level up the network. After that, I came across few configuration:

- Some of the request were not getting logged in neither `access.log` or `error.log` files of `nginx`.
- Domain Registered at Go Daddy was having NS Records of Wiplon Server.
- Wiplon Server had a subdomain created with with redirection to aws server.
  Also it has record set of A ip-4 address redirection.

I have created a diagram for understanding:

[image]

This resulted in traffic to move to either of both wiplon server and record set, 
 which was the root cause of the problem.

**Solution:**
Removal of the SubDomain Redirection from Wiplon Cpanel resolved this issue. Also Make Sure there is only one A ip4 Record present in DNS Zone made the problem solve 100%.

I haven't faced this kind of issue earlier, because we generally assume that the higher level network configurations and already well handled by the domain and DNS provider.

I never faced any connectivity issue on any ios or android device after that.